# Does a Stance go down if the players character goes Unconscious?

Tags: dnd-4e

Does a `Stance` go down if the player's character goes `Unconscious`?

Comment: If a player goes unconscious you should probably stop the game and call an ambulance ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes.**

From the stance DDI entry:

> **Duration:** A stance last until the character assumes another stance or until the character falls unconscious or dies.

When a PC goes `Unconscious` their stance ends.